# How to put something directly to the right of another thing (HTML/CSS)?

Tags: html, css

Basically what I have is an HTML page with a "main content" block, if you will. All main content for that page goes in the div I have for it. What I want is to have a column with more stuff to the right of it, but whatever I try to do it always ends up going either below it or in some random place. Here is the code for my page, if anyone could help guide me through it that would be awesome.

HTML: http://pastebin.com/Hh2TNGdj
CSS: http://pastebin.com/ZCEJkFmH

Thanks.

Comment: The new column must be placed to the right of `<div id="pagecontent">`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, but float:right; doesn't work when I try that, and I'm not sure how else I could.

Answer (score 1):

You were probably close... putting in your new div straight after `#pagecontent`, and floating it right, then floating the `#pagecontent` div left, will allow them to sit side by side.

Note that the next content (footer, for instance) will need to be cleared properly so it won't overlap your floated divs.

Answer (score 1):

I would switch to using HTML5 tags, personally.  If I were to do something like this, I would go with code along this line (untested):

```
    <div id="wrapper"> #wrap both sections in a container
        <section id="left">Left Section</section>
        <section id="right">Right Section</section>
    </div>
```

For the CSS, you can do something like this:

```
    #wrapper {
        width: 1000px;
        height: auto;
    }
    #left {
         width: 500px;
         height: auto;
         float: left;
     }
    #right {
          width: 500px;
          height: auto;
          float: left;
     }
```

Some important things to remember.  If you add padding, subtract that from the width (if padding is on both left and right, subtract padding x2).  On your footer, put clear: both.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: ...Or use `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: ... and carefully explain, in both cases, what steps are needed to make it work on IE8 and maybe IE7-

Comment: For IE, don't use HTML5 or CSS3. Just have one box that is the width of the two inner boxes combined. Set `float:left` on the two inner boxes. If the combined width of the two inner boxes is greater than the outer box, they won't sit next to each other. You may have to set `overflow:auto` on the outer box so that it doesn't collapse.

Comment: Also, don't use IDs for this sort of thing. Use classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6D7U/

- new div `#aside`,
- both columns are floating with fixed width (700+20+240 pixels here),
- last CSS rule is there because parent has only floating children and thus no more content in the flow to push down the background...

Comment: That's awesome, thank you. However, it's not exactly what I meant. I meant like a whole separate box completely to the right of the #pagecontent, not within it. Is there any way you could tell me how to do that instead?

Comment: I assumed `.main-content-font` was your left column. If not, find which block should be the left column, add #aside right after in the HTML code. Note what id or class has their common parent. In CSS add a width on this parent, `float: left;` both columns and add a width on each (the sum of widths+padding+border should equal the width of the parent. 960px is a common value but that's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
<div style="padding:20px;">
        <div id="pagecontent">
                <span class="main-content-font">
                            The title of this page goes in the gray box above. This is the homepage, you can put <u>anything</u> here  (the main content of your website
                            which has some neat features and explains what your site is about should go here)!<br />
                            <br>
                            Content, content, and more content!<br />
                            <br>
                            Try to make it fill up as much space as possible, making the page longer. Don't fill it with useless junk, just anything
                            you can think of that will benefit the page.
               </span> 
               <span class="whatever">
                    some things
               </span>
        </div>
</div>
```

I haven't tried it, but making `main-content-font` a span will not add a newline, so the `whatever` span will be placed to its right.